# Why is temporary Node necessary in Reversing a linked list in cpp?

Tags: c++, linked-list

**Here is the working code:**

```cpp
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *next;
    Node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current -> next;
        current -> next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;

    return head;
}
```

**And this doesn't work when I remove the temporary variable current.**

```cpp
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *prev = NULL;
    // Node *current = head;
    Node *next;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        next = head -> next;
        head -> next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

I understand that we need `next` since we have to keep track of it before losing access to it. But I cannot think of why  the temporary variable `current` is necessary? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For a simple list (perhaps only three nodes), draw it on paper using a pencil. Boxes for the nodes, labeled boxes for the variables, and arrows for the pointers. Now using pencil and paper, perform the operations in the code, erasing and redrawing the arrows as you modify the pointers. What are the differences between the functions in your drawings?

Comment: it's actually not necessary (despite the name may be confuse) as you don't really use `head` in first snippet.

Comment: yeah, I got it now, the problem wasn't in the `head` itself. The head is pointed towards the last NULL in the second code snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `current` variable. (despite it's name `head` would be confusing)

---

The code is different because you don't assign `prev` to `head` in the second snippet.

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *prev = NULL;
    // Node *current = head;
    Node *next;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        next = head -> next;
        head -> next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next;
    }
    
    // or head=prev; return head;
    return prev; // <--- 
}
```